# Trying to display DIV from URL parameters in Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ujs

In Rails 3 I have a URL that I want to visit (http://localhost.com/display_div_a_and_hide_div_b) and I want it to hide and display the respective divs.

I have the following in my routes file:

```
get 'users/display_div_a_and_hide_div_b' => 'controller#display_div_a_and_hide_div_b'
```

But I'm at a loss to know what to put into the specific controller action to display and hide these divs. I'm using UJS rather than prototype so am unable to use the render :update method.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Is there some reason you need to encode everything in the url? Couldn't you just have an action `controller#display` and then have information about the options sent in parameters? Your view, for example, could look like this:

```html
<% unless params[:div_a] == "hidden" %>
  <div id="div_a">
    ...
  </div>
<% end %>

<% unless params[:div_b] == "hidden" %>
  <div id="div_b">
    ...
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Then all you have to do is send the parameters to hide or show whatever parts you want.

Comment: Sorry, the user is not coming to the URL from inside the rail app. They're coming to it from outside so I can't pass it via params. It has to be via the URL string itself.

Comment: You know you can pass params via the URL string, right? `users/display?div_a=hidden&div_b=shown`

Comment: Thank you. That was the solution. I didn't realize you could pass params to rails via the URL!